# Tkinter programming 2

Tags: tkinter

Here as i originally begin with few widgets and then try to add more widgets by deleting the previous ones(i had asked this earlier and got a reply, but the problem still persisted). On trying to remove the previous widgets, an imprint is left. Please help me remove this or suggest an alternative.

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):

  def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)                 
    self.master = master
    self.init_window()
  def init_window(self):   
    self.master.title("SAMPLE")
    self.pack(expand=1)
    loginb = Button(self, text="Log in",command=self.LogIn)
    loginb.grid(row=1)

  def Quit(self):
        exit()
  def LogIn(self):
        for widget in Frame.winfo_children(self):
              widget.destroy()
        self.grid_forget()
        self.grid()
        e1
        self.L = {}
        Label1 = Label(text="Enter your code:").grid(row=1,column=0)
        E1 = Entry(textvariable=e1).grid(row=1,column=1)
        def  F1():
              self.L["Code"] = e1.get()
              return
        B1 = Button(text="Ok", command=F1).grid(row=1,column=2)
root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x700")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this question is lacking a lot of context. Who is @Lafexlos, and what changes did they ask you to make? What do you need help with? All you've done is posted some code without asking a question.

Comment: `var = Widget().grid()` always assign `None` to `var` because `grid()` returns `None` - you have to do `var = Widget()` and `var.grid()`

Comment: what is `e1` in code ???

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use `parent` in widgets ie. `Label(self, ...)` so automatically you put widgets into `root` (Main Window), not into `self` (Frame). And later you remove widgets from `self` but elements in `root` stays.

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):

  def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)                 
    self.init_window()

  def init_window(self):   
    self.master.title("SAMPLE")
    self.pack(expand=1)

    l = Button(self, text="Log in", command=self.login)
    l.grid(row=1)

  def remove_all(self):
    for widget in self.winfo_children():
      widget.destroy()

  def login(self):
    self.remove_all()

    self.var = StringVar()

    self.L = {}

    l = Label(self, text="Enter your code:")
    l.grid(row=1, column=0)

    e = Entry(self, textvariable=self.var)
    e.grid(row=1, column=1)

    b = Button(self, text="Ok", command=self.fun)
    b.grid(row=1, column=2)

  def fun(self):
    self.remove_all()

    self.L["Code"] = self.var.get()

    l = Label(self, text="Code: " + self.L["Code"])
    l.grid(row=1, column=0)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x700")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

You can use another `Frame` to group widgets and remove this `Frame` with all widgets inside

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):

  def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)                 
    self.init_window()

  def init_window(self):   
    self.master.title("SAMPLE")
    self.pack(expand=1)

    # create empty `f`    
    self.f = Frame(self)
    self.f.pack(expand=1)

    l = Button(self.f, text="Log in", command=self.login)
    l.grid(row=1)

  def login(self):
    # remove old `f`
    self.f.destroy()

    # create empty `f`    
    self.f = Frame(self)
    self.f.pack(expand=1)

    self.var = StringVar()

    self.L = {}

    l = Label(self.f, text="Enter your code:")
    l.grid(row=1, column=0)

    e = Entry(self.f, textvariable=self.var)
    e.grid(row=1, column=1)

    b = Button(self.f, text="Ok", command=self.fun)
    b.grid(row=1, column=2)

  def fun(self):
    # remove old `f`
    self.f.destroy()

    # create empty `f`    
    self.f = Frame(self)
    self.f.pack(expand=1)

    self.L["Code"] = self.var.get()

    l = Label(self.f, text="Code: " + self.L["Code"])
    l.grid(row=1, column=0)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x700")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```